# php publish message to google cloud pubsub

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-pubsub

How do I post a message to a topic using curl (or PHP). I tried copy/paste'ing the sample code an I get an error: Invalid JSON payload received
Any help would be appreciated!

```
curl -X POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[projectname]/topics/[topicname]:publish
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
     -H "Authorization: key=[mykey]"
     -d '{"name": "name", "email": "email"}'
```

Comment: Take a look at [this docu](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish). At the right part you have the TryThisAPI window which is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put your data inside the messages tag.

For your case, please try

```
curl -X POST \
  https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[projectname]/topics/[topicname]:publish \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <<generated access token>>' 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: pubsub.googleapis.com' \
  -d '{
  "messages": [
    {
      "name": "name", "email": "email"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Please let us know if you encounter any further problem. Thanks